# SQL LIKE % inside array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I know how to perform an SQL LIKE % query for a single value like so:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE %tom%;
```

but how do I do this if the search terms for my LIKE comes from an array? For example, let's say we have an array like this:

```
$words = array("Tom", "Smith", "Larry");
```

How do I perform my SQL LIKE % to search for the words in my array like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE %[each_element_from_my_array]%
```

WITHOUT putting the whole query inside a foreach loop or something

**EDIT** : I forgot to mention that I'm doing this in cakePHP inside the conditions of the cakePHP find('all') method, so that complicates things a little bit.

Thanks

Comment: Your question has at least `5` votes for the [tag:like-operator] tag. Could I kindly request that you suggest [tag:sql-like] as a [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/like-operator/synonyms)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$sql = array('0'); // Stop errors when $words is empty

foreach($words as $word){
    $sql[] = 'name LIKE %'.$word.'%'
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE '.implode(" OR ", $sql);
```

---

Edit: code for CakePHP:

```
foreach($words as $word){
    $sql[] = array('Model.name LIKE' => '%'.$word.'%');
}

$this->Model->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => $sql
    )
));
```

Read up on this stuff: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions

Comment: my thought exactly. nice answer!
just need to be careful when having an empty array which would cause SQL error...

Comment: I think `OR 0` would do just fine... ;)

Comment: This will work, but how do I do this inside the cakePHP find('all') function (See edit)

Comment: I know this is old, but just struck me how this would be open to sql injection - what with security being a hot topic atm thought I'd raise it

Answer (score 29):

In case of standard SQL, it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%tom%' 
                       OR name LIKE '%smith%' 
                       OR name LIKE '%larry%';
```

Since you're using MySQL you can use [`RLIKE` (a.k.a. `REGEXP`)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name RLIKE 'tom|smith|larry';
```

Comment: `RLIKE` happened to be an absolutely great solution for me, thanks!! ;)

Comment: my column 'name' needs to be wrapped in 'lower' function, does it make the query slow on multiple 'or's and 'like's?

Comment: `RLIKE` saved the day. Thanks a bunch, kind internet stranger

Answer (score 4):

You can't. It'll have to be a chained `field like %..% or field like %..% or ...`. A `where ... in` clause only does extract string matches, with no support for wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

try using [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

```
SELECT * FROM users where fieldName REGEXP 'Tom|Smith|Larry';
```

Answer (score 0):

i just took the code of 472084.

```
$sql = array('0'); // Stop errors when $words is empty

foreach($words as $word){
    $sql[] = 'name LIKE %'.$word.'%'
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE '.implode(" OR ", $sql);
```

For my self, i had to modify it because it's returned me an error SQL.
I Post it for people who gonna read the thread.

```
foreach($words as $word){
    $sql[] = 'name LIKE \'%'.$word.'%\'';
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE '.implode(" OR ", $sql);
```

The difference between them is about quote, my mysql DB said there is a problem ! so i had to escape quote from `$sql[] = 'name LIKE %'.$word.'%'`
and now it's work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

/**
 * Implode a multidimensional array of values, grouping characters when different with "[]" block.
 * @param array $array The array to implode
 * @return string The imploded array
 */
function hoArray2SqlLike( $array )
{
    if ( ! is_array( $array ) ) return $array;

```
$values  = array();
$strings = array();

foreach ( $array as $value )
{
    foreach ( str_split( $value ) as $key => $char )
    {
        if ( ! is_array( $values[ $key ] ) )
        {
            if ( isset( $values[ $key ] ) )
            {
                if ( $values[ $key ] != $char )
                {
                    $values[ $key ]     = array( $values[ $key ] );
                    $values[ $key ][]   = $char;
                }
            }
            else
                $values[ $key ] = $char;
        }
        elseif ( ! array_search( $char , $values[ $key ] ) )
            $values[ $key ][] = $char;
    }
}

foreach ( $values as $value )
{
    if ( is_array( $value ) )
        $value = '['.implode( '', $value ).']';

    $strings[] = $value;
}

return implode( '', $strings );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In this code we can't get double quotes in sql query

```
$sql = array('0'); // Stop errors when $words is empty

foreach($words as $word){
    $sql[] = 'name LIKE %'.$word.'%'
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE '.implode(" OR ", $sql);

SELECT * FROM person where name like %"Tom"% OR name like %"Smith"% OR name like %"Larry"%;
// error in double quotes and % is out side of Double quotes .
```

Or you can also use comma separated value:-

```
$name = array(Tom, Smith, Larry);

$sql="SELECT * FROM person";

    extract($_POST);
    if ($name!=NULL){
    $exp_arr= array_map('trim', explode(",",$name));
    echo var_export($exp_arr);
    //die;
        foreach($exp_arr as $val){
        $arr = "'%{$val}%'";
        $new_arr[] = 'name like '.$arr;
        }

      $new_arr = implode(" OR ", $new_arr);
      echo $sql.=" where ".$new_arr;
    }
        else {$sql.="";}
```

Echo sql query like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM person where name like '%Tom%' OR name like '%Smith%' OR name like '%Larry%';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
With just one extra line of code :)

```
$words = array("Tom", "Smith", "Larry"); 

$words = implode("%' OR `name` LIKE '%", $words);
// result -> Tom% OR `name` LIKE %Smith% OR `name` LIKE %Larray

$menus = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE '%" . $words . "%'";
// result -> "... WHERE `name` LIKE %Tom% OR `name` LIKE %Smith% OR `name` LIKE %Larray%";
```

Comment: Please share more details - is this any better than the existing answer?

Answer (score -2):

Many SQL systems let you push it as a character value. CHAR(10) = Linefeed. So, occasionally, instead of working out all the escape coding, you can push single quotes, double quotes and other things into a sql string this way, without too many other coding issues.

-Just a hint.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: Please share more details - how is this even related to the given question?