# ActiveRecord find records that start with one of the words in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know this below query will find records that have a field's value starting with a certain prefix.

```
MyModel.where("field LIKE ?", "#{prefix}%")
```

What is the query to find records that have a field's value starting with one of the words in an array?

EDIT: I found solutions to other languages here: [SQL LIKE % inside array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416062/sql-like-inside-array) and btw, I'm using MySQL DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
prefixes = ['mega', 'hyper', 'super']
sql_conditions = prefixes.map{ |prefix| "field ILIKE #{sanitize("#{prefix}%")}" }.join(' OR ')
MyModel.where(sql_conditions)
```

---

In my IRB console:

```
prefixes = ['mega', 'hyper', 'super']
sql_conditions = prefixes.map{ |prefix| "field ILIKE #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize("#{prefix}%")}" }.join(' OR ')
# => "field ILIKE 'mega%' OR field ILIKE 'hyper%' OR field ILIKE 'super%'"
```

---

**An alternative, for MySQL only:**

```
prefixes = ['^mega', '^hyper', '^super'] # the ^ wildcard represents the start of line
sql_conditions = "field RLIKE '#{prefixes.join('|')}'" # RLIKE is also known as REGEXP
MyModel.where(sql_conditions)
```