# SQL SELECT WHERE NOT LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an array:

```
$codes = array (97121, 97122, 97123, 97180);
```

The real array is much longer, it contains nearly 130 codes so I think it doesn't have to be a loop.

And I have a mySQL table that has a column **`VilleAnn`** (city with postal code) ex:

- Sainte-Anne 97180
- Sanary-sur-Mer 83110

Using mysqli I have to select where **`VilleAnn`** doesn't contain any postal code from the array **`$codes`**.

If the **`VilleAnn`** is a simple postal code I would say:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE VilleAnn NOT IN(97121, 97122, 97123, 97180)
```

But in this case it must be something using `NOT LIKE "%..."`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you use an inner query to fetch the postal codes instead of having them as a long list of numbers in a `NOT IN` clause?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416062/sql-like-inside-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In condition doesn't work with the wildcard characters. Your best bet is to try and extract the postcode from the original field, in this example

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE right(VilleAnn,5) NOT IN ('97121', '97122', '97123', '97180')
```

I presume real life is more complicated, so this might need to be adjusted to reflect the actual format of the field.

Answer (score 3):

You could you REGEXP:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE VilleAnn NOT REGEXP '97121|97122|97123|97180|....'
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE (
    `VilleAnn` NOT LIKE '%97121%' AND 
    `VilleAnn` NOT LIKE '%97122%' AND 
    `VilleAnn` NOT LIKE '%97123%' AND 
    `VilleAnn` NOT LIKE '%97180%'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE VilleAnn NOT REGEXP '[0-9]';
```

This will help you.

For to check four times occurrences you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE VilleAnn NOT REGEXP '[0-9]{4}';
```