# Select substring from column

Tags: php, mysql

I have this functions

```
  public function returnArticlesByTag($tag)
{
return Db::queryRows('
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `keywords` like `%?%` limit 10;
', array($tag));
}

public static function queryRows($query, $parameters = array())
{
$return = self::$connection->prepare($query);
$return->execute($parameters);
return $return->fetchAll();
}
```

I want find if string '$tag' is included in table 'article' in column 'keywords'

When I call function 'returnArticlesByTag' with string I have this error.

Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '%?%' in 'where clause' in C:\laragon\www\models\Db.php:37

37 in DB is row with $return = self::$connection->prepare($query);

I tried use answer from possible duplicate. Now I have not any error. By select selected 0 rows. And its not correct.

```
public static function queryMYRows($query, $parameters = array())
  {
    $return = self::$connection->prepare($query);
    $return->execute(array('%value%'));
    var_dump($return);
    return $return->fetchAll();
  }
public function returnArticlesByTag($tag)
  {
    return Db::queryMYRows('
    SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `keywords` like ? limit 10;
    ', array($tag));
  }
```

Comment: @revo Iam not sure if is it dupliacte, because i have problem  use his answer on my project

Comment: Check this answer. It has an example on how to send array in LIKE.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416062/sql-like-inside-array